# Individual Datatable column searching through keyup event works, but draw() function doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have used jQuery Datatable using datatable.bundle.js. Everything is working fine but when I use a `keyup` event on individual column search inputs, the event fires but `column.search(this.value).draw();` doesn't work.

```js
this.api().columns().every(function(index) {
  let column = this;
  $('#user-data input').on('keyup change', function() {
    //alert("changed");
    console.log("key is pressed");
    //column.search(this.value).draw()
    //console.log("inside");
    if (column.search() !== this.value) {
      column.search(this.value).table.draw();
    }

  });
}
```

I've tried this

```js
this.api().columns().every(function(index) {
  let column = this;
  $('#user-data input').on('keyup change', function() {
    //alert("changed");
    console.log("key is pressed");
    //column.search(this.value).draw()
    //console.log("inside");
    if (column.search() !== this.value) {
      column.search(this.value).table.draw();
    }
  });
}
```

The event is working but draw function is not working

Comment: Do you receive any error?

Comment: No Julien , please help I'm struck badly from 2 days

Comment: Can you debug into the .draw() code line and show us the evaluations of each part of this code line? And please provide a link to the documentation of the plugin you are using.

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: In the documentation the code is `column.search(this.value).draw();` without the `table`. Could you please check if that is working for you?

Comment: this is working fine

Answer (score 0):

According the [documentation](http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html), you need to remove `table` from your method call.

```
column.search(this.value).draw();
```

instead of

```
column.search(this.value).table.draw();
```